# creating binary search trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assume that your tree is constructed by inserting, from left to right, the values
 Q = {7; 6; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1} into the tree starting from an empty tree.

I have to Give an array of Q that compels the tree to have the largest and one which has  shortest height possible.

One of The problem is I don't exactly know what it means by when it says "inserting from left to right"... Could someone help me do this question.

THANK You very much indeed!

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use Q = {1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7;}

Using the insertion algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion

```
void insert(Node* node, int value) {
    if (value < node->key) {
        if (node->leftChild == NULL)
            node->leftChild = new Node(value);
        else
            insert(node->leftChild, value);
    } else {
        if(node->rightChild == NULL)
            node->rightChild = new Node(value);
        else
            insert(node->rightChild, value);
    }
}
```

So, as you iterate through the list, Q, you are adding to the tree.

So Q = {7; 6; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1} would produce the longest.

```
                    7
```

Since 6 is less than 7, and 7 does not have a left child, it is added as a left child.

```
                    7
                   /
                  6
```

Starting from the top. Since 5 is less than 7, compare to the next left child. since 5 is less than 6, and 6 does not have a left child, it is added as a left child. Following this logic through the list produces the following tree.

```
                    7
                   /
                  6
                 /
                5
               /
              4
             /
            3
           /
          2
         /
        1
```

Q = {4; 2; 1; 3; 6; 5; 7;} would produce the shortest.

Start with 4.

```
                         4
```

Compare 2 to 4, since 2 is less than 4 (and 4 has no left child), 2 is added as a left child to node 4.

```
                         4
                        /
                       2
```

Compare 1 to 4, since 1 is less than 4 (and 4 has a left child), compare to 4's left child. Since 1 is less than 2 (and 2 has no left child), 1 is added as a left child to 2.

```
                         4
                        /
                       2
                      /
                     1
```

Compare 3 to 4, since 3 is less than 4 (and 4 has a left child), compare to 4's left child. Since 3 is MORE than 2 (and 2 has no RIGHT child), 3 is added as a RIGHT child to 2.

```
                         4
                        /
                       2
                      / \
                     1   3
```

Compare 6 to 4, since 6 is more than 4 (and 4 has no right child), 6 is added as a right child to 4.

```
                          4
                        /   \
                       2     6
                      / \
                     1   3
```

Keep going produces the following graph.

```
                          4
                        /   \
                       2     6
                      / \   / \
                     1   3 5   7
```

Answer (score 0):

It means quite simply that the values in the list are inserted in the order in which they are written. That is, if the list is $\{a;b;c\}$, then $a$ is inserted first, $b$ is inserted second, and $c$ is inserted last.